# My elif is returning the result of my if statement instead even though I changed the conditions

Tags: python, sql, database, mysql-connector

I am making a python application to take data from an sql database. I am making it accept user input. If "all" is typed in, it will return all the data, if a specific country is stated then only that information will be returned. Even though I am specifying that Canada should only return the Canada data, it still returns all of the data. My sql query works, I already tried it.

I tried switching around the if and elifs but then it only returned the Canada data and nothing else.

```
def get_employees(mycursor):
        while(True):
            try:
                print("\n-----------Employees Per Country-------------")
                first_choice = input("Enter country name for specific country or (All) to view all countries:")
                if first_choice == "All" or "all":
                    sql_query = "SELECT * FROM EmployeesPerCountry;"
                    mycursor.execute(sql_query)
                    query_result = mycursor.fetchall()
                    for record in query_result:
                        print(f"Country Name: {record[0]} \nNumber of Employees: {record[1]}\n")
                    return 
                
                elif first_choice == "Canada" or "canada":
                    sql_query = "SELECT * FROM EmployeesPerCountry WHERE country_name = 'Canada';"
                    mycursor.execute(sql_query)
                    query_result = mycursor.fetchall()
                    for record in query_result:
                        print(f"Country Name: {record[0]} \nNumber of Employees: {record[1]}\n")
                    return 

                
            except Exception as err:
                print(f"An error has occured: {err}\n")
            continue
```

Comment: The `or "all"` part always evaluates to true. You need to compare `first_choice` to `all` instead

Comment: Change your if condition to if (first_choice == "All") or (if first_choice == "all")